# SQL to get WordPress posts with category and post_tag

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I want to export from database list of posts with category and tag. I tried this [Wordpress SQL: get post category and tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48271265/wordpress-sql-get-post-category-and-tags) but it doesn't work on my MySQL 5.7.27 with errors

```
Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'wpdev.c.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

My expecting result would be the same

```
+---------------+----------+----------------+
| post_id       | category | tags           |
|---------------+----------+----------------+
| 213           | news     | tag1,tag2,tag3 |
+---------------+----------+----------------+
```

My statement is:

```
SELECT p.id, p.post_name, c.name, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) 
FROM wp_posts p JOIN wp_term_relationships cr on (p.id=cr.object_id) 
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ct on (ct.term_taxonomy_id=cr.term_taxonomy_id and ct.taxonomy='category') 
JOIN wp_terms c on (ct.term_id=c.term_id) 
JOIN wp_term_relationships tr on (p.id=tr.object_id) 
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt on (tt.term_taxonomy_id=tr.term_taxonomy_id and tt.taxonomy='post_tag') 
JOIN wp_terms t on (tt.term_id=t.term_id) 
GROUP BY p.id
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include your actual SQL code for best results here.

Comment: ```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.post_name,
    c.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.`name`)
FROM wp_posts p
JOIN wp_term_relationships cr
    on (p.`id`=cr.`object_id`)
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ct
    on (ct.`term_taxonomy_id`=cr.`term_taxonomy_id`
    and ct.`taxonomy`='category')
JOIN wp_terms c on
    (ct.`term_id`=c.`term_id`)
JOIN wp_term_relationships tr
    on (p.`id`=tr.`object_id`)
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt
    on (tt.`term_taxonomy_id`=tr.`term_taxonomy_id`
    and tt.`taxonomy`='post_tag')
JOIN wp_terms t
    on (tt.`term_id`=t.`term_id`)
GROUP BY p.id
```
@TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

If you use aggegate functions as `GROUP_CONCAT` you have to use `GROUP BY` for **all** non aggegate columns in the result.
So change `GROUP BY p.id` to `GROUP BY p.id, p.post_name, c.name` and the error disapears.

To get more information about the `only_full_group_by` mode you can read this  [What are the benefits of only_full_group_by mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484068/what-are-the-benefits-of-only-full-group-by-mode) for example.