# How to Split Categories and Tags into Two Different Columns when Querying Wordpress Posts.?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, concatenation, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to split the results I get from querying        wp_terms.`name` into two columns, one containing the "Category" entries and the other the "Tags" to go along with the rest of the query I got out of creating an editable table with WPDATATABLES´s query generator (wordpress plugin for displaying front-end editable databases: https://wpdatatables.com)

Here's the code I managed to come up with:

```
SELECT wp_posts.`ID`,
       wp_posts.`guid`,
       wp_posts.`post_title`,
       wp_posts.`post_content`,
       wp_postmeta.`meta_value`,
       wp_users.`display_name`,
       wp_terms.`name`
FROM wp_users
  INNER JOIN wp_posts
     ON wp_posts.`post_type` = 'post'
     AND wp_posts.`post_status` = 'publish'
     AND wp_users.`ID` = wp_posts.`post_author`
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
     ON wp_postmeta.`meta_key` = 'user_submit_url'
     AND wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id`
  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
     ON wp_postmeta.`post_id` = wp_term_relationships.`object_id`
  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
     ON wp_term_relationships.`term_taxonomy_id` = wp_term_taxonomy.`term_taxonomy_id`
  INNER JOIN wp_terms
     ON wp_term_taxonomy.`term_taxonomy_id` = wp_terms.`term_id`
```

Everything is looking good except for the splitting of categories and post_tags into two different columns.

I have tried to implement the solution found here:

[Wordpress SQL: get post category and tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48271265/wordpress-sql-get-post-category-and-tags)

But obviously to no success (also because I am forced to use WPDATATABLES´ query generator which is very picky when I make big changes to the code.)

I appreciate any kind suggestion whatsoever and thanks in advance for the patience (I'm a total newbie with some small, but very specific needs I am trying to figure out.)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thank you. I guess I am not being clear enough after reading your link. I will try to rephrase my question according to you guidelines.